# Как сконвертировать SVN-репозиторий с Google Code в git?

Tags: git, svn

Я так понял, Google Code закрывается и SVN-сервер больше не держит. Скачал source-archive.zip с него, внутри него лежат:

```
branches
.svn
tags
trunk
wiki
```

В `trunk`, который я тоже пытался checkout'ить, лежат `.svn` и все файлы проекта.

И, собственно, что со всем этим дальше делать? Так как сам я svn не знаю и хочу git, пытался копипастить команды из гугла (поэтому просьба не смеяться при чтении ниженаписанного :), но что-то не катит.

Пытался в `git svn clone file:///path/to/directory` или `git svn clone file:///path/to/directory/trunk` — ругается, что «No repository found».

`svnserve -d -r /path/to/directory` и просто `svn checkout svn://localhost` с разными вариациями ссылки — аналогично «No repository found».

`subgit` захотел от меня сервер в интернете, а где мне его взять-то, если `svnserve` отдавать отказался.

Comment: *Скачал source-archive.zip* — это просто архив с файлами, а не репозиторий (с ревизиями, ветками и прочим). соответственно, конвертировать не из чего. можете просто создать новый репозиторий и добавить в него файлы/каталоги.

Comment: Вы можете создать новый git-репозиторий, закинув в него все файлы из предыдущего svn. Или нужно, чтобы история коммитов также сохранена была?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению вы опоздали. Вся ваша история была удалена 25 января 2016 года. Все что вы можете сейчас сделать - это взять содержимое этого архива и закоммитить в git в качестве начального состояния.

PS папки .svn и все их содержимое коммитить точно не нужно.

Comment: Присутствие каталогов `.svn`  в архиве и отображение списка коммитов на сайте тоже ничего не значат?(

Comment: @andreymal нет, не значат. Они указывают, что это рабочая копия (причём от очень старой версии SVN). В рабочей копии SVN нет полноценной истории ревизий. Репозиторий свой и историю изменений вы потеряли. Молодец, гугл.

Comment: Эх-эх, ладно, буду гит с нуля делать